# Launch modal on page load after loggin in successfully

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-modal

i want to load this modal on the page where a user will be directed to after logging in successfully and would automatically close after a few seconds and can be closed by the user after pressing anywhere

modal:

```
<div class="welcome-modal modal-bg" id="welcome-modal">
    <div class="welcome-text">
        <div class="message-bg">
            <p class="message-text">Welcome</p>;
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="G-image">
        <img src="../global-img/welcome.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

PS: don't know much about javascript and just only have a few knowledge in php

Comment: Where is your JavaScript? What part of the problem are you struggling with? Your question does not say anything, make a jsfiddle if you can with your existing code that shows what you have tried so far.

Comment: that's the point, don't know the codes for JavaScript to do it, I've only tried to echo it with php but sadly it didn't show up

Comment: What modal library have you used. Where is that information

Comment: The bootstrap documentation is pretty clear on how to show a model programatically, just gotta use `$("#welcome-model").modal("show");`

Comment: on a separate file

Comment: i know that, tho i dunno how to execute it without using a button...the login form, the modal and the page where the user will be directed to are all on different files

Comment: You don't need to use a button to call `.modal("show")`; it can be called when the page loads with something like `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` or similar. Probably going to need to include all your relevant php files.

Comment: kinda getting what you're saying, where should i put that js tho?? the page where i want it to pop up???

Comment: Yup :) You'd have a `<script>` in your `.php` file that calls that, and as long as `jquery.js`, `bootstrap.js` and your modal html are loaded before you call `.modal("show")`, it should pop up.

Comment: i see thanks :D one last thing, is there a JavaScript function that closes it after a few seconds???

Comment: Yup, `window.setTimeout(function(){ $("#welcome-modal").modal("hide"); }, 1000);`, where `1000` is the time in ms you want to elapse before the `function()` is called. Check the events logic for modals and see if you can attach that to the `on("shown.bs.modal")` listener.

Comment: Happy to help. Give those suggestions a try, and if you have any specific issues, feel free to either update this question or post a new one. Cheers!